# Laravel and React full API : login to site A log me on site B too

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, session, csrf-token

I'm using this project to make a full API application : https://github.com/justnixx/laravel-breeze-api-react using Laravel and React (I'm new to react and laravel).

Everything is ok on it, I've made the following DNS :
front.project.local:3000 (react frontend)
back.project.local:8000 (laravel backend)

Now I would like to make an administration site, so i duplicated the frontend project and made admin.project.local:3001 so that I have a new site with its own pages for administration.

I've configured all for both sites to work with the laravel backend.

Now my problem is, when i log in to front.project.local:3000, it also log me in to admin.project.local:3001 (same browser, 2 differents tabs). I dont want this, I would like each subdomain to have its own session.

In the laravel project i can see in folder storage/framework/sessions that only 1 session file is created for both sites and I dont understand why.

Am I missing something ? Or is it normal that only 1 session file is created ?

Any hints would be appreciated ;)

In both React projects I'm poiting to BACKEND_URL: "back.project.local:8000"
front is requesting to /* or /api/*
admin is requesting to /admin or /api/admin/*

In Laravel project .env I have the following configuration :

```
    APP_URL="back.project.local:8000"
    FRONTEND_URL="front.project.local:3000"
    FRONTADMIN_URL="admin.project.local:3001"
    ...
    #to prevent cors issues
    SESSION_DOMAIN=".project.local"     SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="localhost:3000,localhost:3001,project.local:3000,admin.project.local:3000,$admin.project.local:3001"
```

All my research are pointing to the opposite solution : people want shared session, me not.
(edit : removed http:// cause stackoverflow think this is spam)

Comment: _"so i duplicated the frontend project"_ - please clarify, does that mean your admin project is a separate Laravel instance now? Or are they both part of the same one? `SESSION_DOMAIN=".project.local"` - that would make the session cookie valid for `project.local` - and all subdomains thereof. So if these _are_ separate Laravel instances, you should make the session cookie explicitly valid for their respective subdomains only.

Comment: If your Laravel application sets cookies http-cookies could be the cause. Especially the "domain" and/or "same-site" attribute. You can read more about http-cookies here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies
You can check if your app uses cookies by checking your session.php in the config folder.

Comment: I duplicated the frontend (react), i have only 1 laravel application.
Folder structure is like that :

Project
- front (react)
- admin (react)
- back (laravel)

Comment: I'm not sure this is the good thing to do. What I would like is to have a login page and an admin login page, both independant with the same backend. My first idea was to have only 1 frontend with something like /login and /admin/login but i've read some post it's not really a good idea to have both front and admin on the same app cause it will load unnecessary js and css for front and admin.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your code that handle the login request `frontend/src/context/AuthContext.tsx`,

Try replacing all occurence of `window.localStorage` to `window.sessionStorage` as a start.

The difference is sessionStorage data is persisted per tab, as opposed to localStorage where it is persisted until someone/some code cleared it. But naturally, either local and session storage are isolated per domain so they don't pollute each other. It could be your applications sees the two frontend applications as same because they shared a domain name / domain is not configured properly between those two.